# How to join several table and group concat into one single query

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have 5 table in my database (bengkel, jenis_jasa, jasa_bengkel, jenis_fasilitas, fasilitas_bengkel).

Here is the detail:

```
bengkel
+---------------------+
|id  | nama           |
|---------------------|
|1   | Manunggal motor|
|---------------------|
|2   | Jaya motor     |
|---------------------|
|3   | Auto 2000      |
+---------------------+

jenis_jasa
+---------------------+
|id  | nama           |
|---------------------|
|1   | servis         |
|---------------------|
|2   | ganti oli      |
|---------------------|
|3   | sspooring      |
|---------------------|
|4   | cuci           |
+---------------------+

jasa_bengkel
+----+----------------+---------------------+
|id  | id_jasa        |id_bengkel           |
|----|----------------|---------------------|
|1   | 2              |1                    |
|----|----------------|---------------------|
|2   | 3              |1                    |
|----|----------------|---------------------|
|3   | 1              |2                    |
|----|----------------|---------------------|
|4   | 1              |3                    |
|----|----------------|---------------------|
|5   | 3              |3                    |
|----|----------------|---------------------|
|6   | 4              |3                    |
+----+----------------+---------------------+

jenis_fasilitas
+----+----------------+
|id  | nama           |
|----|----------------|
|1   | mushola        |
|----|----------------|
|2   | majalah        |
|----|----------------|
|3   | makanan        |
|----|----------------|
|4   | pijat          |
+----+----------------+

fasilitas_bengkel
+----+----------------+---------------------+
|id  | id_fasilitas   |id_bengkel           |
|----|----------------|---------------------|
|1   | 2              |1                    |
|----|----------------|---------------------|
|2   | 4              |1                    |
|----|----------------|---------------------|
|3   | 1              |1                    |
|----|----------------|---------------------|
|4   | 1              |2                    |
|----|----------------|---------------------|
|5   | 2              |2                    |
|----|----------------|---------------------|
|6   | 1              |3                    |
|----|----------------|---------------------|
|7   | 2              |3                    |
|----|----------------|---------------------|
|8   | 3              |3                    |
|----|----------------|---------------------|
|9   | 4              |3                    |
+----+----------------+---------------------+
```

So far I have tried this code...but it only a half of the desired result

```
SELECT fasilitas_bengkel.id_bengkel, bengkel.nama as bengkel, 
GROUP_CONCAT(jenis_fasilitas.nama) as fasilitas_combined
FROM fasilitas_bengkel
INNER JOIN jenis_fasilitas
ON fasilitas_bengkel.id_fasilitas = jenis_fasilitas.id
INNER JOIN bengkel
ON fasilitas_bengkel.id_bengkel = bengkel.id
GROUP BY fasilitas_bengkel.id_bengkel

Output:
+----+----------------+-----------------------------+
|id  | bengkel        |fasilitas                    |
|----|----------------|-----------------------------|
|1   | Manunggal motor|majalah,pijat,toilet         |
|----|----------------|-----------------------------|
|2   | Jaya motor     |mushola, majalah             |
|----|----------------|-----------------------------|
|3   | Auto 2000      |makanan,mushola,pijat,majalah|
|----|----------------|-----------------------------|

Desired output:
+----+----------------+-----------------------------+------------------------+
|id  | bengkel        |fasilitas                    |Jasa                    |
|----|----------------|-----------------------------|------------------------|
|1   | Manunggal motor|majalah,pijat,toilet         |ganti oli,spooring      |
|----|----------------|-----------------------------|------------------------|
|2   | Jaya motor     |mushola, majalah             |servis                  |
|----|----------------|-----------------------------|------------------------|
|3   | Auto 2000      |makanan,mushola,pijat,majalah|servis,spooring,cuci    |
|----|----------------|-----------------------------|------------------------|
```

Please help, how can I do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the tables you provided, you just need to join with related tables and GROUP_CONCAT on the jenis_jasa.name:

```
SELECT fasilitas_bengkel.id_bengkel, bengkel.nama as bengkel, 
GROUP_CONCAT(jenis_fasilitas.nama) as fasilitas_combined,
GROUP_CONCAT(jj.nama) as Jasa
FROM fasilitas_bengkel
INNER JOIN jenis_fasilitas
ON fasilitas_bengkel.id_fasilitas = jenis_fasilitas.id
INNER JOIN bengkel
ON fasilitas_bengkel.id_bengkel = bengkel.id
INNER JOIN jasa_bengkel jb
ON jb.id_bengkel=fasilitas_bengkel.id
INNER JOIN jenis_jasa jj
ON jj.id=jb.id_jasa
GROUP BY fasilitas_bengkel.id_bengkel;
```